# Does upgrading Ubuntu kernel change its release name?

Tags: kernel, lsb-release

I installed Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS on machine and have upgraded its kernel version to 4.2 with the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-wily
```

I was a bit confused about kernel version and release name. Some software provides binaries for different releases: Trusty, Utopic, Vivid, Wily, ...

In this case, should I download a binary for Trusty or that for a newer release name as far as the software provides?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ubuntu releases and the kernel versions are independent from each other.

Open a terminal and check the Ubuntu release version with this command :

```
lsb_release -a
```

The output shows something like :

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 15.10
Release:    15.10
Codename:   wily
```

Open a terminal and check the running kernel version with this command :

```
uname -r
```

The output shows something like :

```
4.2.0-22-generic
```

This was a PC running Ubuntu 15.10 - here is a PC running Ubuntu 14.04 :
[If you opt into the hardware enablement stack for Ubuntu 14.04 (Trusty)](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/TrustyTahr/ReleaseNotes#LTS_Hardware_Enablement_Stack),
the outputs will show that the release still is 14.04 and the kernel is 3.19.

```
lsb_release -a  

No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty  

uname -r  

3.19.0-42-generic
```

Comment: For non-LTS releases kernel major versions are always same unless it is manually changed. For LTS it is quite different.

Answer (score 4):

Upgrading your LTS release to a newer kernel line does not change the release name.

So you still have Ubuntu 14.04 trusty.

See about [HWE](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack)

LTS releases allow to install kernels from non-LTS main releases.

`linux-generic-lts-wily` installs the kernel from 15.10 "wily" release.
It will be default in Ubuntu 14.04.4.

This may be a bit confusing.